# LookUpError in TensorFlow with tf.cond()

Tags: tensorflow

**Work environment**

- TensorFlow release version : 1.3.0-rc2
- TensorFlow git version : v1.3.0-rc1-994-gb93fd37
- Operating System : CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

**Problem Description**

I use `tf.cond()` to move between training and validation datasets at the time of processing. The following snippet shows how I have done :

```py
with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope()) as vscope:
        for i in range(4):
            with tf.device('/gpu:%d'%i):
                with tf.name_scope('GPU-Tower-%d'%i) as scope:
                    worktype = tf.get_variable("wt",[], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
                    worktype = tf.assign(worktype, 1)
                    workcondition = tf.equal(worktype, 1)
                    elem = tf.cond(workcondition, lambda: train_iterator.get_next(), lambda: val_iterato\
r.get_next())
                    net =  vgg16cnn2(elem[0],numclasses=256)
                    img = elem[0]
                    centropy  = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=ele\
m[1],logits= net))
                    reg_losses = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES, scope)
                    regloss = 0.05 * tf.reduce_sum(reg_losses)
                    total_loss = centropy + regloss
                    t1 = tf.summary.scalar("Training Batch Loss", total_loss)
                    tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
                    predictions = tf.cast(tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(net), 1), tf.int32)
                    correct_predictions = tf.cast(tf.equal(predictions, elem[1]), tf.float32)
                    batch_accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(correct_predictions)
                    t2 = tf.summary.scalar("Training Batch Accuracy", batch_accuracy)
                    correct_detection.append(correct_predictions)
                    grads = optim.compute_gradients(total_loss)
```

So basically based on the value of `worktype`, a minibatch will be taken from training or validation set.

When I run this code, I get the following `LookUp Error` :

```
LookupError: No gradient defined for operation 'GPU-Tower-0/cond/IteratorGetNext_1' (op type: IteratorGetNext)
```

Why does `TensorFlow` think that `IteratorGetNext_1` requires a gradient ? How can I remedy this ?

Comment: I assume it's because the variable `worktype` is marked as trainable. `optim.compute_gradients(total_loss)` computes the gradients for all trainable variables by default. Try to set `trainable=False` in `tf.get_variable()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It corrected the problem and it also clarified the training concept very well.

Comment: Ok, I will add an answer then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `worktype` is marked as trainable. By default, [Optimizer.compute_gradients(...)](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#compute_gradients) computes the gradients for all trainable variables.

There are two ways you could solve this:

1. Set `trainable=False` in [tf.get_variable(...)](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable).
2. Explicitly specify the variables for which the gradients should be computed with the `var_list` argument of [Optimizer.compute_gradients(...)](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#compute_gradients).